# Several unary operators in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Is it standard-conforming to use expressions like

```
int i = 1;
+-+-+i;
```

and how the sign of i variable is determined?

Comment: Why dont you check it yourself?

Comment: @LeeNeverGup what do you mean by checking?

Comment: Compiler might even optimize out that line: `+-+-+i;`

Comment: @LeeNeverGup: As C++ has a bad habit of reminding us, just because you *can* doesn't mean it's *legal*.  However, in this case, yes.  The sign would be determined the way you'd expect.

Comment: As far as the language standard is concerned, yes, it's conforming. For the coding standard, the answer should be "Hell, no!".

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is. Unary `+` and `-` associate right-to-left, so the expression is parsed as

```
+(-(+(-(+i))));
```

Which results in `1`.

Note that these can be overloaded, so for a user-defined type the answer may differ.

Comment: Turns out it doesn't matter what order they're parsed in because unary negation and positivization are associative for integral types.

Comment: @Wug in this case, no. It will probably even be optmized out completely.

Comment: What if they were left-associative? Would it be `((((+-)+)-)+)i`? That's nonsense; i'd not call them right-associative, or in any way associative at all.

Comment: @anatolyg what if the world was flat? They are right-associative whether you like it or not.

Comment: Left/right associativity is a property you can assign to binary operators. It makes no sense for unary ones.

Comment: `+++` parses as `++ +` because of the way lexer works (it always tries to form the longest possible token). I don't see how associativity has anything to do with that.

Comment: @avakar after further investigation - you're right - but the reference still holds. Actually, this might be a good question.

Comment: Unary operators can be prefix or postfix. You could call all prefix operators "right-associative" and all postfix operators "left-associative", but that would be of little value, and I've never heard those terms used in such a way. As for your reference, note that it is not a quote from the standard, operator precedence and associativity come implicitly from the grammar.

Comment: @avakar ah - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12961372/673730 it's a good point. If it were left-associative - `(--x)++` vs `--(x++)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, that's not associativity, that's precedence. In `++x++`, the two `++` are actually different operators.

Comment: @avakar yes, saw that in the other answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your operators has no side effect, `+i` do nothing with int itself and you do not use the temporary generated value but remove `+` that do nothing and you have `-(-i)` witch is equal to `i` itself.(removing `+` in the code will convert the operator, I mean remove it in computation because it has no effect)

Comment: If you remove the `+`, you're left with `--i`, which is a whole different story.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Please read again my answer I already addressed this in end of my answer

Comment: You mean "removing + in the code will convert the operator, I mean remove it in computation because it has no effect"? Yeah... I don't understand that, but if this is what you meant, then ok...

Answer (score 0):

`i` isn't modified (C: without intervening sequence points|C++: in an unsequenced manner) so it's legal. You're just creating a new temporary with each operator.

The unary `+` doesn't even do anything, so all you have is two negations which just give `1` for that expression. The variable `i` itself is never changed.